# When trying to use reactive data I am getting invalid property 'id' of bean class [reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly]

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

I am trying to use thymeleaf form along with single valued reactive data stream. Using spring boot 2.1.3, thymeleaf 3.0.11 and webflux.
My POJO is:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RecipeCommand {
    private String id;
    private String description;
}
```

controller is:

```
@GetMapping("/recipe/{id}/update")
public String updateRecipe(Model model, @PathVariable String id){

    Mono<RecipeCommand> recipeCommandMono = recipeService.getRecipeCommandById(id);
    model.addAttribute("recipe", recipeCommandMono);
    return "recipes/recipeform";
}
```

where recipes/recipeform is thymeleaf form to update recipe:

```
<form  th:object="${recipe}" th:action="@{/post}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
```

Application run but when trying to update recipe I got below error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly]: Bean property 'id' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Any idea how to use thymeleaf form with reactive streams.

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.gabriel</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-recipe</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-recipe</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>popper.js</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: could you share your pom.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass **Mono** to your template. Instead of that you can wrap **Mono** with **IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable** object. IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable works with **Flux** so you should use **flux()** method to convert **Mono** to **Flux**.

```java
@GetMapping("/recipe/{id}/update")
public String updateRecipe(Model model, @PathVariable String id){

    Mono<RecipeCommand> recipeCommandMono = recipeService.getRecipeCommandById(id);
    IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable recipe = new ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable(recipeCommandMono.flux(), 1);
    model.addAttribute("recipes", recipe);
    return "recipes/recipeform";
}
```

change thymeleaf part (variable recipes is now async list)

```html
<div th:each="recipe : ${recipes}">
    <form  th:object="${recipe}" th:action="@{/post}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
```

Comment: IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable are expected to wrap multi valued streams like Flux. When trying to wrap Mono one get error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Reactive Data Driver context variable was set single-valued asynchronous object. But data driver variables must wrap multi-valued data streams (so that they can be iterated at the template

Comment: I updated answer. If you don't want to use Flux and then iterate over it you can use .block() to unwrap Mono and get requested data

Comment: when using flux error appears from thymeleaf form that id is not readable. blocking is also not possible and gives error  java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-epoll-1

Comment: No there is no block() method. Method returns Mono<RecipeCommand>.

Comment: When you used IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable, did you change the thymeleaf template? IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable gives a stream, not an object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205287/discussion-between-niebian-and-gabriel-gamrat).

Answer (score 1):

I switched to spring boot 2.2.2.RELEASE. It solved problem. Now thymeleaf accepts Mono when passed as model attribute. No changes were required neither to controller nor to form template.